# How to add Search layouts in Salesforce package

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, salesforce-chatter

I was experimenting with the salesforce Package creation (Upload) and installation. I have done some important changes in Opportunity & Products **Search layouts** and I wish them to get added in the final Package. When I am creating the package I am able to add only the following Components.
Analytic Snapshot
Apex Class
Apex sharing Reason
Apex Trigger
App
Button or Link
Custom Field
Custom Object
Custom Report Type
Custom Setting
Dashboard
Document
Email Template
Field Set
Folder
Home Page Component
Home Page Layout
Letterhead
List view
Page Layout
Permission Set
Profile Settings
Record Type
Remote Site
Report
S-Control
Static Resource
Tab
Validation Rule
Visualforce Component
Visualforce Page
Workflow Email Alert
Workflow Field Update
Workflow Outbound Message
Workflow Rule
Workflow Task
I have tried my best but was unable to add the **Search Layouts** into my package.
Please Help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can move the whole object from one side to the other by using the Force.com IDE or the Ant tool. Haven't tested it, but it should also move the search layouts.

Comment: Hi vertibadev, your solution will work only for custom made objects in SFDC but this is not so for the Standard objects already present in a salesforce environment. Well, I am still grateful for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to add Search Layouts, but couldn't find them in the list of components either. After some quick research I found that it's currently impossible to add Search Layouts for Standard sObjects (like Account, Contact, etc). I believe they can be added for custom objects (it looks like they're brought over with the object definition itself), but I haven't checked for sure.

Here's an idea you can vote up, if you'd like, to convince Salesforce to add the ability to add Search Layouts to the platform:
http://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000JmLsAAK

Comment: Hi Matthew,
Thanks for your Answer/Suggestion. I have also voted for the idea on SFDC to add Search Layouts in Packages.

Comment: It looks like this issue is closed and was for adding them to change sets not packages?