# Can we create new Search Layout in Lightning SalesForce?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am working on the Srearh Layout, and instead of **Default**, I want to create **Custom Search Layout** and assign to a profile.

Is that possible to create Custom search Layout.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add Search layouts in Salesforce package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067099/how-to-add-search-layouts-in-salesforce-package)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a different Search Layout per Profile. You have to navigate to the object page and select *Search Layouts*. Then you can apply a different one per profile.

Please keep in mind that you'll have to set the *Einstein Search* Permission Set on the Profiles with a Custom Search Layout, otherwise it will not work.

[image]